# Snake Lemma Weibel 1.3.2

Tags: category-theory, homology-cohomology, abelian-categories

I'm reading An introduction to homological algebra by Charles A. Weibel and I'm trying to prove the snake lemma 1.3.2.
[Using this diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AMFna.png) (don't have enough points to embbed it in my question) it says that $\partial=c_0^{-1} f_1b_1^{-1}$ makes the sequence $\ker(f_0)\to\ker(f_1)\to\ker(f_2)\overset{\partial}{\to}coker(g_0)\to coker(g_1)\to coker(g_2)$ exact. However, Using $c_0^{-1}$ and $b_1^{-1}$ would mean that they are isomorphisms. Which they can't be since the sequence is supposed to be exact and $\ker(f_0)\to \ker(f_1)$ isn't the $0$ map.
Does anyone know what it could be please?

Answer (score 0):

These preimage notations can just mean... preimage, rather than inverse. For example under $f:\Bbb R\to\Bbb R,x\mapsto x^2$, $4$ has a preimage, $2$ (say) but that does not mean $f$ is an isomorphism. Arguments are made to show the $c_0,b_1$ in question do in fact have preimages under the relevant maps. All of this needs to be suitably interpreted if one works in an arbitrary Abelian category.

Comment: So if it were to be rigorous, it'd be using the axiom of choice to construct a map between those two? How do we know it's a morphism?

Comment: @Jolia I think it's possible to prove this with no choice. Weibel tends to not work with general Abelian categories, or only very cursorily/sloppily work with Abelian categories, but we can prove the existence of $\partial:\ker\to\mathrm{coker}$ using only universal properties of these objects. Then you have to check $\partial$ is actually exact, which requires some kind of chase, but once it is known to exist I think that chase works without AC. But hey, AC is used *all the time* in algebra and category theory, almost all modern maths to be honest. It is rigorous not to mention it

Comment: To check it's well-defined independently of the choices of preimage, you argue as Weibel argues. To check that it's appropriately additive, e.g. it's a map of modules, you can argue by hand. For example, if $x$ is a preimage of $c_0$ and $y$ is a preimage of $c_0'$ then $x+y$ is a preimage of $c_0+c_0'$, so you can use that choice

Comment: used Category for the working mathematician to prove it using universal properties!

Comment: @Jolia Great! Yes, I much prefer Mac Lane's treatment of Abelian categories